# Flutter: Text toolbar (selection, cut, copy, paste) for TextField inside CupertinoTabView is not clickable

Tags: flutter, cupertinotabbar

The `TextField` inside a `CupertinoTabView` is not allowing to select, copy, paste, cut the text using the toolbar. The toolbar is not clickable.
But when the CupertinoTabView ancestor is removed, it is working without any issues. 
I need the `CupertinoTabView` as an ancestor for pushing more routes inside the tab.

The toolbar is clickable again when there is some space (around 80px) below the `TextField`.